# Morphisms $h: G \to H$ and $f: G \to K$ such that there are at least two different morphisms $g_i : K \to H$ such that $h = g_i \circ f$ $(i=1,2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just saw the fundamental theorem of morphisms, and I was wondering: Is there an example of two homomorphisms $h: G \to H$ and $f: G \to K$ such that there are at least two different homomorphisms $g_i : K \to H$ such that $h = g_i \circ f$ $(i=1,2)$?

Is anyone is able to give me a hint about the existence of those homomorphisms?

Comment: There is a mismatch in composing these maps. $g_i \circ f$ has $G$ as a domain, while $h$ has $K$ as a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy example: let $G = K= \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $h$ is the zero-homomorphism $h\equiv 0$ and $f$ is the homomorphism $f(n + 4\mathbb{Z}) = 2n + 4\mathbb{Z}$. Then there are two different $g_i$ which result in $h = g_i\circ f$: we can take $g_1$ to be the zero-homomorphism $g_1\equiv 0$ and $g_2$ to be the parity homomorphism $g_2(n + 4\mathbb{Z}) = n + 2\mathbb{Z}$.